# Is a good edge flow essential for uv-mapping and texturing?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

i'm busy trying to make a guitar in Blender and I wondered if it's necessary to have a better edge flow in the head of the guitar when I am going to UV-unwrap the mesh. I have no shading problems and there are no Ngons or triangles present in the mesh. But when I create an edge in the head of the guitar the flow of the edge is really bad as you can see here:
[image]

[image]
This problem started when I created the holesin the head with the boolean modifier. Is this going to create a problem for me in the future. Should I try to clean up the mesh till I get a good edge flow?
Thx for your help!

Comment: Cleaning up a mesh is always a good idea as it promotes good practice of edge flow. However I can see that you have some sort of weird faceting going on (marked in red) and I've drawn, in blue how you'd go about fixing that. You need edges in there or you'll get that weird thing going on. Can you maybe disable the subdivision so I can get a better look at the topology? As it stands triangles and n-gons don't really affect the UV map if you unwrap it correctly but, as I said, understanding good topology will serve you  well in the future.
https://gyazo.com/413fb2b6dc1cbc79853c4c80128f4900

Comment: I have added another picture without subdivision. I should really learn how to clean up meshes especially after using the bool tool.

Comment: With circular shapes you typically want to keep the topology flowing like this:
https://gyazo.com/56d5bfde069d002cc571a1b0b3e35cd3
It just keeps things neater and such and presents good edge flow. To answer your question about UVW unwrapping you can add a colour UV grid to see how the UV's will affect a texture. Then apply said texture to your model. Unless you already knew that lol
https://gyazo.com/34b6b4b3826c4ef70e2e67075929fcff

Comment: Ah yeah I knew, but thanks for the tip anyway haha. Thanks for your help! I will try to make the topology more like you suggested. :)

Comment: A good rule of thumb is "if it looks awkward then it probably is." Just keep at it and you'll develop a sort of gut instinct for that sort of thing ^.^

Comment: Damnit time to remake the whole guitar then :)

Comment: No don't say that! Just use the knowledge you now have for the next project! You'll never learn anything if you keep starting again lol.